# Is it possible to convert lowercase to uppercase AND remove accents in the same function using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, diacritics

I´m writting a PHP code where `$posted_data['name']` is my variable.
In order to convert it to UPPERCASE letters, I´m using the following: (which is working pretty well)

```
$uppercase = $posted_data['name'];
$uppercase = strtoupper($uppercase);
```

However I´m willing to know if is it possible to implement in the same line another function the letter accentuation removal or a clean up way to do it.

**E.g.:**

User´s String input: João

String output: JOAO

So, there are two functions running here in this desired situation:  one to convert from lowercase to uppercase and the other one removing the accents.

Comment: It's possible, what have you tied so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some magic in here where it converts the diacritical marks to non-diacritical characters and then converts the letters to uppercase.

```
<?php

function slug($string) {
    return strtoupper(trim(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ' '));
}

$string = 'João';
echo slug($string);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1042865)

Here's the same example broken down into separate lines for each function call to make how it works clearer:

```
function slug($string) {
    $str = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $str);
    $str = trim($str, ' ');
    return strtoupper($str);
}
```

Comment: Call it whenever you want to capture that value. It looks like before the line of code you just posted I would say put this line above it: `$name = slug($posted_data['name'])` Then use `$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $name);`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you would use that.

Comment: It´s running OK  :-)

Answer (score 1):

PHPs unicode support (ext/intl) can do that in a single call:

```
$string = 'Hello ÄöÜ!';
var_dump(
    \Transliterator::create('Any-Upper; Latin-ASCII')->transliterate($string)
);
```

Output:

```
string(10) "HELLO AOU!"
```