# xml add encoded xhtml in xml element using php

Tags: php, xml, xhtml, encode

I want to create xml file which embed encoded xhtml. I has encoded xhtml file separately. During creating xml element, I would like to add the encoded content of xhtml in xml element, `test`. After I add and echo the final output to browser, error shown in browser.

> This page contains the following errors:
> error on line 9 at column 144: Encoding error
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

```
    <?php    
     $dom                   =new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
     $content = (file_get_contents("test_xmlencoding.xhtml"));
     $element = $dom->createElement('test', $content);
     $dom->appendChild($element);
     header('Content-type: text/xml;');
     echo $dom->saveXML();    
    ?>
```

XHTML file

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" ?&gt;
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;meta content="TX21_HTM 21.0.406.501" name="GENERATOR" /&gt;
&lt;title&gt;&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:12pt;text-align:left;"&gt;
&lt;p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:'Verdana';font-size:9pt;"&gt;ABC1.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:'Verdana';font-size:9pt;"&gt;(ABC2)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:'Verdana';font-size:9pt;"&gt; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:'Verdana';font-size:9pt;"&gt;ABC3&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
```

When add xhtml content without encoding, the output render without error on browser.

I has try replaced

```
$content = (file_get_contents("test_xmlencoding.xhtml"));
```

to

```
$content = htmlentities(file_get_contents("test_xmlencoding.xhtml"));
```

The output show only the ending tag of test element, `</test>`.

Comment: Please clarify, is what you call an "XHTML file" actually XHTML - or just _encoded text_, as the example you have shown? It tested your code as shown with both versions, and the resulting XML passed a check for wellformed-ness in both cases.

Comment: it is encoded xhtml. I want to append it to xml element.  The `encoded xhtml `work only when I remove space between >,`&gt;` and <,`&lt;`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If I take the output of https://3v4l.org/MPQGc and put it through https://www.xmlvalidation.com, it says everything was fine, no errors.

Comment: And what are you actually trying to achieve by this? Might it not perhaps make more sense to stick this into a CDATA section? https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php

Comment: I had tried with different part of XHTML. It works here, https://3v4l.org/Uer9u#v7.2.30. But, my site showing error `This page contains the following errors:
error on line 8 at column 78: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.` I remove space between every `&gt; &lt;`, then  it run without error

Comment: _"on line 8 at column 78"_ - and what exactly is at that position?

Comment: &lt;p lang="en-US" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:'Verdana';font-size:9pt;"&gt;A&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: Column 78 in that would be between the `l` and `e` of the second `style`, can't see that making sense. (Did that line start directly at position 0, in your actual output?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `DOMDocument::createElement()` and the `DOMNode::$nodeValue` property have only a partial escaping. They expect special characters to be already escaped as entities - except `<` and `>`.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild(
  $tests = $document->createElement('tests')
);
$tests
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('test', 'a < b'));
$tests
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('test', 'a & b'));
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference b in ... on line 9
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tests><test>a &lt; b</test><test/></tests>
```

The method argument is not part of the DOM standard and the property behaves different from the specification.

In original DOM you where expected to add the content as a separate text node. This allows for mixed child nodes, too. Modern DOM introduced the `DOMNode::$textContent` property which acts as a shortcut.

Here is an example:

```php
$xhtml = <<<'XHTML'
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <em>a &amp; b</em>
  </body>
</html>
XHTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild(
  $tests = $document->createElement('tests')
);
// append child element and set its text content
$tests
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('test'))
  ->textContent = $xhtml;
// append child element, then append child text node
$tests
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('test'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode($xhtml));  
  
$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:
Take note of the double escaped `&amp;amp;`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tests>
  <test>&lt;?xml version="1.0" ?&gt;
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
  &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;em&gt;a &amp;amp; b&lt;/em&gt;
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</test>
  <test>&lt;?xml version="1.0" ?&gt;
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
  &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;em&gt;a &amp;amp; b&lt;/em&gt;
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</test>
</tests>
```

Comment: This method help to encode entity of xhtml automatically after append the xml element. It has helped me.  Thank you. Now, I am finding decode entity of xhtml because my source document is a entity encoded xhtml.

Comment: If you load the source as HTML, DOM will decode the named entities. https://3v4l.org/PgeeM#v8.1.2 - otherwise it will only decode numeric entities.

Comment: I have used utf_decode() on loaded xhtml content to remove `Â`[it appear in empty space]. Then, I replacing "\r\n", "\r" to "\n" because `&#13;` appear at the end of every line. `$doc>loadHTML($html);                                                       
$decoded_content=utf8_decode($doc->documentElement->textContent); $normalisdlf_1 =str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $decoded_content);`                          Thank you.

Comment: Rather then decoding the UTF-8 you should consider using it as your default encoding for everything. `utf8_decode()` converts utf-8 to latin-1, any character not available in latin-1 will be lost/broken. So except in very rare cases like exports for other systems that do not understand it, always use utf-8. For normalizing texts check the ext/intl transliterator (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602898/497139).

Comment: when I want to use transliterator, Its ask to install PECL extension before use. I did not proceed. I have tried in replacing non breaking space, &nbsp [encoded in utf-8: "\xc2\xa0"] with empty string. The Â no more appearing in output file. `$removenonbreakingspace_1=str_replace("\xc2\xa0",' ',$xhtml);
$doc->loadHTML($removenonbreakingspace_1);                                                                $decoded_content_1=$doc->documentElement->textContent;                                        $final=str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $decoded_content_1);`

Comment: Here is a [Transliterator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) in the ext/intl standard extension. I think you stumbled upon the older translit extension. Why are you replacing the non breaking space?

Comment: I have tried using transliterator. It works after I added `extension=php_intl.dll` in php.ini and restart xampp. But, `Transliterator::create('Any-Upper; Latin-ASCII')->transliterate($normalisdlf_1);` convert `Â` to `A`. This character appearing extra in empty space of xml. This character should be removed. Entity decode of &nbsp; is \xc2\xa0. `\xc2\xa0` is a nonbreaking space, encoded in UTF-8. This shown as  `Â` in xml. So, I replace `\xc2\xa0` with ' ' which will not show the  `Â` in xml

Comment: The `Â` are typically a sign that you display UTF-8 as Latin-1. Either at some point you call `utf8_encode()` on an utf-8 string or you're not telling the receiving client that you send utf-8 so it falls back to latin-1 or ascii.